# Jquery - Retrieve comments from a Youtube-video using the Api

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

how can i get the last 50 comments from a Youtube-video using the Api?

http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

Here u can generate a Url. But there is no function like -> 
give all comments by using the youtube-id

Thanks in advance
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. It's in the second column under community. Click the query button. It allows you put in the youtube ID and get the videos comments.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the response format it´s something like a request to:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/YOUR_VIDEO_ID/comments?v=2&max-results=50

That´s it